# I am trying to make a 2d map generation algorithm using python, and the classes will not take the inputs i provide?

Tags: python

```
self.map = [[]*self.mpsiz[0]]*self.mpsiz[1]
print(self.map)
for x in range(self.mpsiz[0]):
    for z in range(self.mpsiz[1]):
        print(x, z)
        self.map[x].append(Cell(x, 1, z, rand.randint(0, 1)))
        print(self.map[x][z].pos)
```

The class Cell should be passed the variables X and Z as inputs, but this is the result from the print statements
 0 0
 [0, 1, 0]
but when the x number ticks over to 1 it prints
 1, 0
 [0, 1, 0]

Here is the class code for Cell()

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, v):
        self.pos = [x, y, z]
        self.value = v
```

and if this helps here is the code for the who project so far...

```
import random as rand
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, v):
        self.pos = [x, y, z]
        self.value = v

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = None
        self.mpsiz = [None, None, None]
        self.cell = None
        self.cell1 = None
    def generate_map(self):
        self.fills_nones()

    def fills_nones(self):
        self.mpsiz = [input('How long should the x be? (default is 500 * 500) ') or 500,
                  input('How far should it be in the z dir ') or 500,
                  None]
        for i in range(len(self.mpsiz)-1):
            self.mpsiz[i] = int(self.mpsiz[i])
        self.map = [[]*self.mpsiz[1]]*self.mpsiz[0]
        print(self.mpsiz)
        print('Beginning map generation')
        print('Beginning the base map generation')
        self.make_base()

    def make_base(self):
        self.map = [[]*self.mpsiz[0]]*self.mpsiz[1]
        print(self.map)
        for x in range(self.mpsiz[0]):
        for z in range(self.mpsiz[1]):
            print(x, z)
            self.map[x].append(Cell(x, 1, z, rand.randint(0, 1)))
            print(self.map[x][z].pos)
        print('Done!')
        print('Beginning the rule runs')
        self.make_full_map()

    def make_full_map(self):
        for x in range(self.mpsiz[0]):
            print('\n')
            for z in range(self.mpsiz[1]):
                print(self.map[x][z].pos)


Map = Map()
Map.generate_map()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the source of your issue, but the very first line in the code you've shown, `self.map = [[]*self.mpsiz[0]]*self.mpsiz[1]`, almost certainly doesn't do what you want. That's creating a list with `self.mpsiz[1]` references to the same empty list (the inner multiplication doesn't do anything useful). You probably want `[[] for _ in range(self.mpsiz[1])]` or maybe `[[None]*self.mpsiz[0] for _ in self.mpsiz[1]]` (the latter would require you to not `append` to the lists later, but rather assign into them, replacing the existing `None` values).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, about the internal multiplication, however that did not solve the problem...I do appreciate your help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having has to do with how you're creating the `map` attribute in your `Map` class. The code you're using is not doing what you want. Instead of getting a list of independent lists, you're getting a list with many references to the same inner list. That's because `some_list * some_integer` doesn't copy of the values in `some_list`, it just repeats the references to the existing items. For immutable values like numbers, that's fine. But for mutable values (like a list), you run into problems when you try to mutate the values later.

The reason you were seeing the same `x` value for all your items is because you were looking up `self.map[x][z]`. Since all the `self.map[x]` values are the same list (regardless of what `x` you used), you're only ever seeing the first set of values that got appended to the list. The others were created, but they're further along (you could get to them with `self.map[0][x*self.mpsiz[1] + z]`).

Instead of building the list of lists with `self.map = [[]*self.mpsiz[0]]*self.mpsiz[1]`, try using `self.map = [[] for _ in range(self.mpsiz[1])]`. This will create a separate empty inner list for each value in the `range`, and so the indexing to print out the positions will work as expected.

Note, another peripheral issue also exists in your code. You're using `Map`, both for the name of a class, and for an instance of it (since you do `Map = Map()`). That's probably not a good idea!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the problem it was quite helpful!, with your help I have fixed the problem!